# typedef array vs. typedef pointer

Tags: c, struct

GMP [declares](https://gmplib.org/repo/gmp/file/tip/mini-gmp/mini-gmp.h) the following structure:

```
typedef struct
{
  int _mp_alloc;
  int _mp_size;
  mp_limb_t *_mp_d;
} __mpz_struct;
```

and then these two type definitions:

```
typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];
typedef __mpz_struct *mpz_ptr;
```

What is the reasoning behind those two separate (and seemingly same) definitions? What is the difference between them?

Comment: `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1];` allows GMP to fake out C and with a "pass by reference"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks! But then what they do need `*mpz_ptr` for? Because it is more "correct" and should be used where ever possible? By "correct" I mean the opposite of "fake out".

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica "possible" -> "convenient".

Comment: In effect you are asking why GMP was designed the way it was.  Quite broad.  How would you have re-done `mpz_add (a, a, b); /* a=a+b */` correctly?  In the Darwin selection of competing approaches,  `typedef __mpz_struct mpz_t[1]` won with its "pass by ref".

Comment: I am not sure why `mpz_ptr` is `typedef __mpz_struct *mpz_ptr;` and not `typedef mpz_t *mpz_ptr;`

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I'm sorry I don't follow: would `mpz_add (a, a, b);` not work with the array (`mpz_t`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although arrays and pointers are *syntactically* very similar, they are *not* the same.

The first `typedef` in your example allows declaration of an object of type `mpz_t`, which will be a *single* `_mpz_struct` object (an array of size `1`); however, because it is declared as an array, its name can be used as a pointer (for example, when passing to a function that requires a pointer to that structure type).

The second `typedef` is a simple pointer. Any variable thus declared will need to have the address of an *actual* structure assigned to it before it can be used (dereferenced).

The latter type will allow changes to the particular object it points to, whereas the former type is a 'fixed' pointer to the particular object (or 'fake' array) declared.

I don't have access to the GMP library, so I can't make an example using that, but the following code may illustrate the subtle difference between the two types:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    int a;
    int b;
    double d;
} MyStruct;

typedef MyStruct MS_t[1];
typedef MyStruct* MS_ptr;

int main()
{
    MS_t mt;
    MS_ptr mp;
    printf("Size of type = %zu; Size of pointer = %zu\n\n", sizeof(MS_t), sizeof(MS_ptr));

    mt->a = 1; mt->b = 2; mt->d = 3.141; // Good - "mt" can be used as a pointer to first (only) element of the array.
//  mp->a = 3; mp->b = 7; mp->d = 3.141; // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR - mp doesn't point to anything.

    MyStruct ms1, ms2 = { 3, 8, 42.42 };
    mp = &ms1;
    mp->a = 2; mp->b = 4; mp->d = 2.718; // OK - mp now points to a valid structure (ms1)

    printf("MT: %d %d %f\n", mt->a, mt->b, mt->d);
    printf("MP: %d %d %f\n", mp->a, mp->b, mp->d);

    // Let's try to change addresses:
    mp = &ms2; // We can change what "mp" points to whenever we like
    printf("MP: %d %d %f\n", mp->a, mp->b, mp->d); // Different address -> different structure -> different data!
//  mt = &ms2; // ERROR: array type 'MS_t' (aka 'MyStruct [1]') is not assignable

    mp = mt; // We can even use "mt" as an address to assign to "mp"
    printf("MP: %d %d %f\n", mp->a, mp->b, mp->d); // This shows the 'first' data set values

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you please expand on the "latter type will allow changes to the particular object it points to"? The very first assignment reads `mt->a = 3;` so it also "changes" the object.

Comment: See my edited code. The assignment `mt->a = 3` changes the **data** in the structure but you can *never* change which structure `mt` points to. But you *can* change what `mp` points to. Does this make things clearer?